# In ReactJS modal body and footer showing twice while loading data form API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am trying to load data from laravel route with axios request in modal, but the modal body and btns showing twice inside the modal. Why does that happen? Below is my code for reference.

```
class PopUp extends React.Component{
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        singleProject:[],
        errs:''
    }
}

singleData(){
    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    const fd={
        '_token':token.content,
        'id':this.props.id,

    }
    return fd;
}
componentDidMount() {
    //reuest for services
    Axios.post('/single/project',this.singleData()).then(resp =>{
        this.setState({singleProject:resp.data});
        console.log(resp.data)
    }).catch(err=>{
        this.setState({errs:err})
        // console.log(err)
    })


}



render() {
    const project= this.state.singleProject;
    return(
        <div>
            <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide} size="xl" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
                {
                    project.map(data=>(
                      <React.Fragment key={data.id}>
                                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                                        {data.project_name}
                                    </Modal.Title>
                                </Modal.Header>
                                <Modal.Body  >
                                <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                            <p>
                            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                            </p>
                            </Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <a href={data.project_live_link} className="btn btn-primary">live</a>
                                <a href={data.project_github_link} className="btn btn primary">github</a>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                  </React.Fragment>
                    ))
                }

            </Modal>

        </div>
    )
}}
export default PopUp;
```

and here is an image of what I am getting on rendering 
[image: click to view modal showing data]

i have tried loading complete data and now i am showing you only by adding project name but modal data is already twice showing under project.map area please guide me why is it happening

Comment: Since you are using `project.map` inside the `Modal` they are getting displayed twice. So ideally if there are 3 objects in `project` then you'll end up seeing 3 of them. What exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are fetching the data, storing it in the local store, and the fetched data is in the form of an Array.

Furthermore you are mapping over this fetched array and for each item in the array you are returning a React Fragment.

This React Fragment is rendering Modal.Header, Modal.Body, Modal.Footer.

Instead of this approach, you should consider a different approach. 
Basically you need to have all the projects displayed in the modal. So think of each project as a

Modal.Header and Modal.Footer should be outside the map function.

```
<Modal>
 <Modal.Header>
  Modal Heading
 </Modal.Header>
   {data.map(project => (
      <div class='project'>
       <div class='name'>{project.name}</div>
       <div class='description'>{project.description}</div>
       <div class='project_link'>
         <div class='live_link'>{data.live_link}</div>
         <div class='github_link'>{data.github_link}</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    )})}
 <Modal.Footer>
  Footer Info
 </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

UPDATE: Make the below changes to your componentDidMount call. I have added some comments before you set the state after you get the results.

```
componentDidMount() {
//reuest for services
Axios.post("/single/project", this.singleData())
  .then(resp => {
    //here the data you are getting is in the form of an array.
    //but you don't need that entire array.
    //all you need is the object sitting at index 1
    //so instead of setting {resp.data} set {resp.data[1]}
    this.setState({
       singleProject: (resp.data && resp.data[1]) || {} 
    });
    console.log(resp.data);
   })
  .catch(err => {
    this.setState({ errs: err });
    console.log(err);
  });
 }
```

After this, you can use the project data normally as you would with any other object. I hope this solves the issue. If not, please share the exact code that you are using currently.

Comment: I have checked it very well there is only one project coming from back end because i am showing project with id like single post, there are project in list when any one click on title that project's data will be shown in this modal

Comment: Okay, then in that case why use map at all. If that's the case, this implementation would rather be even more simpler. At the click of any item in the list of projects, grab the corresponding data for the project, such as the description,  links, etc.
Use that object to simply render information in the modal.

Comment: yes i forgot this point, thanks for this, i am going to try this

Comment: please check my answer below

Comment: @ZeeshanAwan I have updated the solution with your doubts. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `state.singleProject` is an array, seems like your are getting two items from the backend, so when you do `singleProject.map` you end up creating two modal bodies and footers.

You should instead change `state.singleProject` to `{}` and have your API to return an object and replace your modal code as below:

```js
    <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide} size="xl" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
          <React.Fragment key={project.id}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                {project.project_name}
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body  >
              <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
              <p>
                Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                            </p>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <a href={project.project_live_link} className="btn btn-primary">live</a>
              <a href={project.project_github_link} className="btn btn primary">github</a>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </React.Fragment>

        </Modal>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: no this modal is for showing details of one project, i am getting data of one project in it with id, like single post, and i have verified it my console.log(resp.data) its detail of only one project getting through specific id

Comment: thanks for you reply. but my problem is solved. please check above answers i have accepted one answer